# Can not resolve reference: 'Stripe' in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mobile, stripe-payments

I'm trying to incorporate Stripe payments into my Xamarin app. I've installed the latest Stripe NuGet Package and have included the following code in my .cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Stripe;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CampaignFinanceNew
{
    public partial class CreditCardProcess : ContentPage
    {

    StripeClient paymentClient = new StripeClient("[test key here]");

    public CreditCardProcess()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreditCard currentCard = new CreditCard();
        currentCard.Number = creditCardNumber.Text;
        currentCard.ExpMonth = Convert.ToInt32(ccExpiryMonth.Text);
        currentCard.ExpYear = Convert.ToInt32(ccExpiryYear.Text);

        StripeObject newToken = paymentClient.CreateCardToken(currentCard);

    }

}
}
```

When I build the project, it gives me the following error:

Error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `Stripe`, referenced by `CampaignFinanceNew`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Stripe`, or remove the reference to `CampaignFinanceNew`. (XA2002) (CampaignFinanceNew.Android)

I've tried to add the Stripe package to both my iOS and Android projects, but it tells me that it's incompatible. What should I do? Would I be better off implementing it individually for both iOS and Android then just accessing it via DependencyService?

Comment: And in which project does CreditCardProcess live? What type of project is it?

Comment: it's in the primary project (not the individual iOS or Android projects)

Comment: What type of project is that? If it is not a "Shared Project" type, then you will need to inject stripe somehow. As you suggest yourself DependencyService would be one way to do it.

Comment: No, it is a .NET project, which likely means DependencySvc will be the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: the Stripe nuget should support netstandard.  DI won't help if the packages don't install in the platform projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research, it appears there are 2 different Stripe NuGet Packages, one specifically written for .NET applications (as opposed to the one I was using). I've downloaded the new package and things seem to be working fine now.